# Could not call contract function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript, nodejs, ethereumjs

I want to access the balance of contract(i.e.  `0x552F3AfaA0394632f4aEfa9E923fA3e2bbDAF5FE`) and its totalSupply(state variable). I could access the balancec of this contract , but why I could not call its function i.e. `getTotalSupply()` I have following code;

```
async function myContractAddress() {
    myContAddr = '0x552F3AfaA0394632f4aEfa9E923fA3e2bbDAF5FE';
    web3.eth.getBalance(myContAddr).then(console.log);
    tokens = await myContAddr.methods.getTotalSupply().call();
    tokens = tokens.toString(10);
    console.log("Toten supply is : ",tokens);

  }
  myContractAddress();
```

here is my error;

```
(node:6028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTotalSupply' of undefined
    at myContractAddress (C:\Users\jj\Desktop\temp\deploy.js:36:39)
    at C:\Users\jj\Desktop\temp\deploy.js:26:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:6028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejectio
 id: 1)
(node:6028) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depr
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
0 // actually this is my contract balance , which have shown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is in your code **myContAddr** is string and you are trying access parameters of this variable. To access .methods.getTotalSupply().call() you need to create contract instance using the following code:

```
async function myContractAddress() {
    var myContAddr = '0x552F3AfaA0394632f4aEfa9E923fA3e2bbDAF5FE';
    var myContractAbiDefenition = 'CONTRACT_ABI';
    var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbiDefenition, myContAddr);
    tokens = await myContractInstance.methods.getTotalSupply().call();
    console.log("Tokens: ",tokens);
}
myContractAddress();
```

Comment: but above address is already deployed on ethereum testnet, then why one function considered it OK (as a contract and gives balance) while other considered it not OK and gives error....